# Provide cancellation token to signalr client

Tags: c#, signalr, signalr.client, cancellation-token

How do I provide a cancellation token to a signalr client, so that I'll be able to stop a long-polling operation?

Can I somehow add it to the `HubConnection` or `HubProxy` or the underlying `HttpClient`?

I didn't find anything on Google :(

Please help.